# How to create an APK file for a binary executable file?

Tags: android, apk, executable

I have written a GUI application in C++, built it for ARM processor and verified, that this application is running on Android in the Andronix emulated environment. Now is the question: How can I enable running this application on Android natively, without any emulated environment? I would like to create an APK file for installing it in a usual way. Are there any tools, which allow creating an APK file and packing an executable file into it?

Comment: Take a look at [San-Angles](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/san-angeles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and `Android NDK` Project and create an APK with your c++ executable.

Official help is here
[Create a new project with C/C++ support](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#new-project)

Answer (score 0):

[Andronix](https://andronix.app/) allows you to run Linux and and Linux executables in an environment separate to the native one - but if you want to run a linux executable on an android, you can do so with much simpler tools, like [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). For example, `adb shell ./sdcard/my_app.pe` would theoretically work.

However, APKs in android are basically zip files that include metadata, and the compiled code as a [dex file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750448/what-are-dex-files-in-android). You would typically use a platform like [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) to generate them from java code.

If you really want to implement things from scratch you probably need to compile your application into a jar file, and then convert it to the dex file using a tool like [d2j](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/dex2jar).