# How to get source file of installed application from an android mobile?

Tags: android

I have downloaded an application on my androids mobile. Now my question can i get source file of that application ? Is there any decompiler available for same ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get the java source code. You can get the assets, drawable and all XML files but that's all. Android uses ProGuard to obfuscate its code.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available for decompiling android source code. [Here](http://divyang4481.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-decompile-android-application-to.html) you can get an idea about how to decompile.