# how to against apk-tool&modify apktool,protect my app?

Tags: android

Please consider the following link:

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/KnownIssues

Towards the bottom it's stated：

> I've found that some APKs don't conform to regular Android standards. They were probably built using a modified aapt, which makes decompiling near impossible. These APKs are called "Magic" apks and probably won't be supported.

So, how do I can protect my app? I'm interested in `modified aapt`, but I have no idea where to begin? Thank you.

Comment: Please see how your question was modified to make it more readable. Try to make the question clear so it's clear to people what you're asking. It helps if you show some effort in writing up your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first search about it, There is some useful link about reverse engineering and decompile .apk files :

- [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-apk-file)
- [decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a lost cause. There are tools that abuse the DEX file format to try to hide your code from popular tools, but they can be easily defeated. 'Near impossible' is a not quite true, just harder to make a general purpose tool for it.

Obfuscate your code, consider using Dex2Jar and above all build a great app so that more people will use it/pay for it.