# Android - Phonegap, Extract code from apk

Tags: cordova

I am new to Phonegap development. I had developed an app and unfortunately i have lost the entire code. But luckily i have the apk file. Can any one pls help me to extract my code from the apk file (PhoneGap - Andriod)
Thanks in advance.

-Vinu

Comment: i have lost my lappy. In which all my code was there. but i found apk in my sentbox. please can you help me in extracting the code from my apk.(PhoneGap - Andriod )

Comment: oh ok. Then is der no way to retreive my source code from apk. thanks so much for de reply

Comment: no warranty or usefullness implied: 


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQN39X9oTi8

Comment: i heard some one saying that v can extract source code from our apk.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. If you copy your .apk file so that is has the .zip extension you should be able to unzip it like any normal zip archive. From that you will be able to retrieve your assest and res folders as well as your AndroidManifest.xml.

If you have written extensive Java code then you will need to decompile the classes.dex file back into Java. Here is a good SO question that covers it:

[decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode)

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to decompile someone else's apk, that's prohibited.

If not **;)** , let's say that you compiled your apk and deleted the project and you need to retrieve it, you can use [Apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to help you with that:

- Download [Apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)  (make sure you've got [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/))
- After installing apktool open node.js
- Find the directory where your target apk is at (using node.js)
- After finding it type on node.js: `apktool d yourApk.apk`
- To build a project type: `apktool b yourProjectFolder`

Hope it helped, if you need some help you can leave a comment that I'll be glad to help you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a much easier way : http://www.decompileandroid.com/ This website uses the programs apktool and dex2jar, but u just have to upload your .apk file. Good Luck