# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: java, android, dalvik, crash-reports, google-play-services

This error is driving me crazy. My app crashes at startup when downloaded from the Google Play Store with the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
```

My app doesn't crash when build from eclipse on our two devices. However a month ago a client used his phone to build our app in and then it also crashed on startup. I ignored the problem then because it was working on our devices and figured it had something to do with Google Map keys or Keystore.

Now it turns out our app crashes on every device when downloaded from the Play Store. I understand that there isn't an easy way to solve this problem but a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

I also find it hard to debug this problem because the app works great when build from eclipse on our devices!

Here is the complete error log that I reported:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.denederlandsewateren.winkeloord/com.denederlandsewateren.views.StartScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.denederlandsewateren.views.StartScreenActivity
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.denederlandsewateren.views.StartScreenActivity
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
... 11 more
```

Again I dont except a straight forward answer to this problem but maybe somebody can shed some light on this problem provided with this error log.

**EDIT**

Here is the Manifest file if thats helpfull:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxx.xxxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxxx.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="my_app_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <service android:name="com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.GCMIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxx" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxxx.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <!--<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.StartScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

Added the verbose log when installing the app on the device

```
03-30 17:56:28.554: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 233K, 68% free 2639K/8195K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
03-30 17:56:28.574: I/dalvikvm-heap(5150): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.682MB for 16777232-byte allocation
03-30 17:56:28.594: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 23% free 19022K/24647K, paused 2ms+9ms, total 21ms
03-30 17:56:29.114: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 23% free 19022K/24647K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-30 17:56:29.129: I/dalvikvm-heap(5150): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.681MB for 9437200-byte allocation
03-30 17:56:29.169: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 17% free 28238K/33927K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 38ms
03-30 17:56:29.254: D/libEGL(5150): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-30 17:56:29.259: D/libEGL(5150): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-30 17:56:29.259: D/libEGL(5150): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-30 17:56:29.284: D/OpenGLRenderer(5150): Enabling debug mode 0
03-30 17:56:32.154: D/KEY(5150): UUID
03-30 17:56:32.179: I/System.out(5150): UUID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
03-30 17:56:32.179: E/SerializeObject(5150): FileNot Found in ReadSettings filename = xxxxx.dat
03-30 17:56:32.184: D/GCMRegistrar(5150): resetting backoff for com.xxxxx.xxxxx
03-30 17:56:32.214: V/GCMRegistrar(5150): Registering app com.xxxxx.xxxxx of senders 752727514714
03-30 17:56:32.214: D/KEY(5150): pushEnabled
03-30 17:56:32.324: V/SlidingMenu(5150): setting padding!
03-30 17:56:32.394: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.394: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.394: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.409: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.414: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.414: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.424: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.424: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.429: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.434: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.434: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.434: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod(5150): Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
03-30 17:56:32.459: V/CustomViewBehind(5150): behind INVISIBLE
03-30 17:56:36.894: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 20031K, 58% free 15574K/36551K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 49ms
03-30 17:56:36.894: D/dalvikvm(5150): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
03-30 17:56:37.504: I/System.out(5150): VaarApp ID: 5
03-30 17:56:37.534: I/Choreographer(5150): Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-30 17:56:37.539: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(5150): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
03-30 17:56:37.544: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(5150): GCM IntentService class: com.xxxxx.xxxxx.GCMIntentService
03-30 17:56:37.549: V/GCMBaseIntentService(5150): Acquiring wakelock
03-30 17:56:37.794: V/GCMBaseIntentService(5150): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-1
03-30 17:56:37.794: E/GCMRegistrar(5150): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
03-30 17:56:37.794: V/GCMRegistrar(5150): Registering receiver
03-30 17:56:37.799: D/GCMBaseIntentService(5150): handleRegistration: registrationId = xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx, error = null, unregistered = null
03-30 17:56:37.799: D/GCMRegistrar(5150): resetting backoff for com.xxxxx.xxxxx
03-30 17:56:37.799: V/GCMRegistrar(5150): Saving regId on app version 1
03-30 17:56:37.829: V/GCMBaseIntentService(5150): Releasing wakelock
03-30 17:56:39.169: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2248K, 52% free 17830K/36551K, paused 6ms+12ms, total 95ms
03-30 17:56:39.169: D/dalvikvm(5150): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
03-30 17:56:39.174: D/dalvikvm(5150): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 48ms
03-30 17:56:41.164: I/dalvikvm(5150): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
03-30 17:56:42.229: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4265K, 49% free 18778K/36551K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 58ms
03-30 17:56:42.229: D/dalvikvm(5150): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 41ms
03-30 17:56:42.234: D/dalvikvm(5150): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 46ms
03-30 17:57:51.759: D/dalvikvm(5150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5476K, 49% free 18775K/36551K, paused 21ms+6ms, total 196ms
```

Comment: Is one build using ProGuard?  I'm wondering if ProGuard is stripping code out because it thinks it's unused.

Comment: If the class does exist (isn't proguarded out), it's possible dalvik is rejecting the class for some reason. If that is the case, you'll see some error messages from dalvik when you are installing the app.

Comment: I added the logs when installing my app. Will look into ProGuard right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it was indeed ProGuard that was stripping code from my project. I use ActionBarSherlock and facebook and this is what I added so it would work:

```
# ActionBarSherlock 

-keep class android.support.** { *; } 

-keep interface android.support.** { *; } 

-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 

-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 




# Keep line numbers to alleviate debugging stack traces 

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile 

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

This for facebook:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd suggest you focus at the difference between the build you are doing from eclipse and the build you are providing to the Play Store.

If you can reproduce the error you see from the playstore, while building it with eclipse and testing it, you will surely find the answer.

What I can think of is the certificates that the app gets signed, but it doesn't seem to be it. However you should think more about what is the difference between the two .apk's - the developer build and the build for playstore.

As .apk are basically archives, you can unzip them both, see differences between them. You should use a dedexer to try and decompile the two instances of classes.dex (see [decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode) ). It will likely be highly obfuscated code, but you should look for missing classes or something like that.

Hope you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project folder => Properties => Java Build Path => Order and Export => check the box "Android Private Libraries" if not checked. And it works !