# Why unable to instantiate application?

Tags: android, exception, google-play

I'm frustrated by this kind of problem, and tried to find all solutions but failed. Please someone who did solved this kindly give me some advice, thank you.

mainifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
package="my.package.name"    
android:installLocation="internalOnly"    
android:versionCode="15"    
android:versionName="v8">    

<application        
android:name="my.package.name.App"        
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"        
android:label="@string/label"        
android:theme="@style/FullBleedTheme"        
tools:replace="android:label"        
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"        >
```

App.java:

```
public class App extends BaseApplication {        

  private static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();     

  public void onCreate() {        
    super.onCreate();
```

google play crash log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application ***.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "***.App" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4539)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "***.App" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
... 11 more
```

[image]

Comment: i found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686593/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass)

Comment: Please double check your packagename in manifest or paste it here at least. Maybe its not pointing to correct packagename. Or you put it on separate subpackage.

Comment: @MarkaA, Thx, I checked, It's ok

Answer (score 2):

replace android:name=".App" with android:name="The full path of 'App' class"

Comment: I did it, no obvious change found till now

Answer (score 1):

Please double check your packagename in manifest or paste it here at least.  Maybe its not pointing to correct packagename.  Or you put it on separate subpackage.

Comment: Please post this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the instant run in android studio. Then build and run. It will work. It worked for me.