# After publishing app on Google play store, strange locked error becoming

Tags: android

App is running good there is no problem, thousands of downloads running there is no error but Android versiyon for 4.+ there is a strange error report coming from developer console. this locked raport:

```
    Samsung Galaxy Note3 Neo (hl3g), 1984MB RAM, Android 4.4
Rapor 18

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2321)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2507)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:172)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5692)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1067)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2312)
```

and this is my gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com...." // I have hided
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 54
        versionName "Canary"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        generatedDensities = []
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false 
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2' 
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.3' 
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'    
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.HITGIF:TextFieldBoxes:1.4.3'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:2.8.0'    
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'    
}   

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the ratio of this error becoming for android versiyon is

> Android 4.4 %84,0
>
> Android 4.2 %13,8
>
> Android 4.3 %2,1

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15723908/7783718).

Comment: well I have no proguard

Comment: Its `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception. You must check if you are trying access a class which doesn't exists.