# Is there a way to find out which tool was used to create a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform

I am getting started with mobile apps development, but there are so many tools available to develop cross-platform apps, so I am really curious as to what was used to build certain apps.

Basically I would like to know if there is something like [PEiD](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD), but for mobile apps, or if there is an easy way to find out what was used to create a certain app I've downloaded from Google's/Apple's App Store (i.e. some sort of file or information inside the apk file).

**EDIT**

After searching a bit more I found this, which may work in a few cases: [decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode)

For instance, I decompiled one game that I had on my Android smartphone (and on my iPad) and found Cocos2d framework inside it.

Comment: There's a lot of diffrent ways to develop mobile apps. What are your goal, are you going for multiple platforms? Are you using hardware features? I like to develop "hybrid" app where I basicly develop a html5 app, where a js interface to the underlying hardware features are used. Fx: cordova.apache.org

Comment: @DNRN I found a lot of "what's the best cross-platform mobile development tool?" questions, but there are too many different opinions. That's why I wanted to find out what the developers of the most popular apps used, which in turn may be some good tools for me to learn. Anyway, regarding your question, I'll probably be making simple stuff for now, a basic 2d game at max. I just don't want to start learning something only to find out that there is another tool way better in almost every aspect

Comment: As @Emmanuel sayes, you can inspect if it's a webview, but not much more though. If you found some statistics, please share them :)

Answer (score 0):

Some cross platform tools let the programmer use web technologies (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) so then they can load these files into a `WebView`. If you were to dump the `View` hierarchy using DDMS you will see a `WebView` on it.

Having said that, the point of these frameworks is to generate the same end result as a native app, so I doubt there will be metadata somewhere in the .apk.