# How can I programmatically decompile dex files within Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I know how to extract apk files to classes using a windows based system as below:

> **Step 1:Renaming .apk file**
>
> Rename the .apk file with the extension .zip (for example let the file
>   be "demofile.apk" then after renaming it becomes "demofile.apk.zip")
>
> **Step 2:Getting java files from apk**
>
> Now extract the renamed zip file in specific folder, for example let
>   that folder be "demofolder". Now Download dex2jar from the link for
>   windows and extract that zip file in folder "demofolder".
>
> Now open command prompt and go to the folder created in previous step
>   and type the command "dex2jar classes.dex" and press enter.This will
>   generate "classes.dex.dex2jar" file in the same folder.
>
> Now Download java decompiler from the link and extract it and
>   start(double click) jd-gui.exe
>
> From jd-gui window browse the generated "classes.dex.dex2jar" file in
>   demofolder, this will give all the class files by src name.
>
> Now from the File menu select "save all sources" this will generate a
>   zip file named "classes_dex2jar.src.zip" consisting of all packages
>   and java files.
>
> Extract that zip file (classes_dex2jar.src.zip) and you will get all
>   java files of the application.
>
> Above steps will generate java files but to get xml files perform
>   following steps.
>
> **Step 3:Getting xml files from apk**
>
> Download apktool and apktool install from the link and extract both
>   files and place it in the same folder (for example "demoxmlfolder").
>
> Place the .apk file in same folder (i.e demoxmlfolder)
>
> Now open command prompt and goto the directory where apktool is stored
>   (here "demoxmlfolder") and type the command "apktool if
>   framework-res.apk" Above command should result in "Framework installed
>   ..." Now in command prompt type the command "apktool d filename.apk"
>   (where filename is name of apk file) This will generate a folder of
>   name filename in current directory (here demoxmlfolder) where all xml
>   files would be stored in res\layout folder.

But I would like to know how to accomplish the above **programatically within Android**. So my android application can simply extract another app's dex file. I don't mind if the dex file is copied elsewhere on the phone, then decompiled (it is simply the decompilation I'm stuck on)

On the principle as below, that **I have access to each app's dex**, just not the knowledge of how to decompile it within Android.

Any help would be fantastic.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
                try {
                    packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("PACKAGE NAME HERE", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                File file = new File(packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: This would require root, as you can't read another process/app's resources, much less their binary as your own app's uid. Just my two cents. PD: Be ready to reimplement a couple classes, Android's Java API does not replicate the full desktop API set

Comment: @Machinarius, It would only require root for private apps. Check out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava. I got it working myself a couple months ago but dex2jar runs super slow on Android.

Comment: I was completeley sure Android's security model wouldn't let you do that without root. I stand corrected. Good job on achieving that, Congratulations. As for performance enhancements... That would require specifically meddling with dex2java's code to make it multithreaded and such.

Comment: Have you seen this

< http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode >

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can browse the sourcecode of the ShowJava application [here](https://github.com/niranjan94/show-java). It looks like he is using the the Dex2Jar tool. The decompilation starts in a [BackgroundService](https://github.com/niranjan94/show-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/njlabs/showjava/processor/ProcessService.java) and all the magic happens in some special Jar classes. I do not know if this code comes from a library or if all this code is created by him. Look at the [ExtractJar](https://github.com/niranjan94/show-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/njlabs/showjava/processor/ProcessService.java#L203) and the [DecompileJar](https://github.com/niranjan94/show-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/njlabs/showjava/processor/ProcessService.java#L240) method than it shouldn't be to hard to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow some steps in order to get it working:

1. Got to the [dex2jar bitbucket site](https://bitbucket.org/pxb1988/dex2jar/downloads) and download the files. Add the jar files to your project.
2. Via the [DexFileFactory](http://code.google.com/p/smali/source/browse/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/DexFileFactory.java), you can load the apk, convert it to dex (`loadDexFile`) and save it to a file (`writeDexFile`).
3. With another library that converts jars to java-files, you can finally read the content. I found [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Decompiler%20API), which seems really simple. Load the class file with an `InputTypeLoader` and then call `Decompiler.decompile()`.

Of course you can use other libraries in step 3, but for step 1 and 2, I haven't found any alternatives.