# Using dex2jar jar file in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sh, dex2jar

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04. I have dex2jar.jar file and i want to use dex2jar to decompile a dex file into jar, but there is no sh file to make it easier and i have no idea how to make one.

Answer (score 3):

You can download .zip file with .sh and .bat files here https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

Unzip it and use like this: 
`sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o output_jar.jar apk_to_decompile.apk`

For more info see - [decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode)