# Take test app from android studio off of phone for use.

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently deleted what I had in terms of an app from Android Studio due to ridiculously bad code. But, I had originally tested the app before the code went crazy. With that being said, I have that part of the app on my phone. Can I take the app off of my phone and put it into Android Studio and pick up where I left off on that? I've read that you can take an .apk and load it into Android Studio, I just don't know where to find it on my phone.

Comment: You are asking to decompile the dex file. There many tutorials which decode `.apk` into dex file and then to java code

Answer (score 1):

You can decompile the .apk, but you can **NOT** turn it into an Android Studio project. And if you enabled proguard when building, the decompiled .java files will be a jibberish.

What you should do is install a VCS like git (it is easy to setup and use) and commit your changes regularly. This way you will always be able to roll the project back in case of trouble.

Comment: Here is more information over decompiling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

In order to get access to the .apk file, you need to use a 3rd party app like appsaver or super saver to save the apk onto your sdcard or internal memory.