# How to import classes from an dex file in Android Studio

Tags: android, class, compilation, dex

I'm trying to import a framework from a third-party project and include it in my project. But when I import the module (using Android Studio), the classes are inside a "classes.dex" file, and I can't import them in my project like as below:

```
import android.os.ThirdPartyClass
```

There are other libraries, but the classes are compiled into .class and not included in a .dex file, so I can import without any problems.

How can I import in this case of .dex file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PREFACE**

This method was deprecated in API level 26.
Applications should use one of the standard classloaders such as [PathClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/PathClassLoader) instead. This API will be removed in a future Android release.

**CONVERTING**

You can compile that `.dex` file into a `.java` file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode/8016997) is a manual how to achieve that. It's really easy and I think answered your question. Good luck! :)

Comment: I tried this already but with no success, I still can't import the classes inside of the .dex converted to .jar file

Comment: I see. You will contact the owner. After that my answer will help you to convert it! Technical it's the correct answer with a previous clarification. Good luck! :)